# content slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a content slider using jquery. I have a div which has alot of text and some sections. and we can scroll down to view the text. It looks something like this [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/jYEpaGOY). Now when the user clicks on one of the jump to option the user should be taken to that section(e.g if user clicks on co-ops it should take him/her to co-ops ) and if the user is scrolling down the text the section which is in focus it should be highlighted in the jump to option

How can I implement it?

Comment: bootstrap has a similar implementation  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 0):

The good solution here could be [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) -
Lightweight, cross-browser and highly customizable animated scrolling with jQuery

index.html

```
<!-- Include jQuery from somewhere, must use version 1.8 or above -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include latest jquery.scrollTo, currently 2.1.0, can download from https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize the plugin, the contents of the script can be inlined here, of course -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
```

init.js

```
// You can avoid the document.ready if you put the script at the bottom of the page
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind to the click of all links with a #hash in the href
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
    // Prevent the jump and the #hash from appearing on the address bar
    e.preventDefault();
    // Scroll the window, stop any previous animation, stop on user manual scroll
    // Check https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo for more customizability
    $(window).stop(true).scrollTo(this.hash, {duration:1000, interrupt:true});
  });
});
```

you can find gist [here](https://gist.github.com/flesler/3f3e1166690108abf747)

Comment: does this highlights the option which is in focus if we simply scroll down not click on the link to go down